# Heroku integration with Rubymine fails with error "Please specify a version along with Heroku's API MIME type." I

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, rubymine

Encountered this problem with a fresh install of Rubymine for Mac, Ruby and Rails and following Roku integration steps in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/heroku-getting-started.html

I tried deleting directory .local/share/heroku and then heroku update, but does not fix the issue, which occurs both when, say trying to upload public key file, and when trying to deploy application with Heroku run configuration.

Comment: For anyone interested, JetBrains response to this problem is "Heroku changed the API" and "They will ask the developer in charge to address this as soon as they get back from vacation."  Caveat Emptor

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19851

They now say 'Support for Heroku deployment will be rewritten for 2017.3 stream.' so that's another three months probably.